# Update ForeignKey Sharepoint List using onSelect button with Patch() - PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-formula

My problem is what I describe in the title.
I want to update a foreign key on my sharepoint list with a button.

I have two List with OneToMany relation:

```
User{ ID, Name, Surname}
Book{ID, Title, Author, ID_User}
```

When I go one user, with a gallery,  i can see the book related with a Filter:

```
Filter(Book,BrowseGallery1.Selected.ID = ThisRecord.IDUser.Id)
```

In this gallery i want to add a Trash and when i click the button remove the Book of this User, soo i want to remove the relation and see only the book related with this user.

I try with:

```
Patch(ThisItem, First( Filter(Book, BrowseGallery1.Selected.ID = ThisRecord.IDAnagrafica.Id)), { ID_User:  0} )
```

But give me an error.
I try this patch with other columns like {Title: "TEST"} and it work.

```
Patch(ThisItem, First( Filter(Book, BrowseGallery1.Selected.ID = ThisRecord.IDAnagrafica.Id)), { ID_User:  ""HERE WHAT I NEED TO SET""} )
```

Thx for help

Answer (score 1):

{ID_User: Value("Your value")}

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Patch-SharePoint-List-Number-Column/td-p/102371

---

EDIT

Look at this answer

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/The-type-of-this-argument-X-does-not-match-the-expected-Type/td-p/599727

from this

```
{ ID_User:  0}
```

to this

```
{ ID_User: {Value:"YOUR ID OR TEXT"} }
```

Comment: I try it but when i put {ID_User: Value("TEST")} or a inputbox give me a error: The function "Patch" has some invalid arguments"

Comment: if column ID_User is number use this {ID_User: Value("0")}

Comment: Nothing. I try to simply my formula with: Patch(Book, Gallery1.Selected, {ID_User: 0)) or Patch(Book, Gallery1.Selected, {ID_User: Value("0:))) but error is always the same: The type of this argument 'ID_User' does match to expected  type ' Record '. Found type ' Number '

Comment: look at my EDIT

Comment: Not work. Now i have 2 different error: "Invalid argument type. Expecting Record value, but of a different schema" and " Missing column. Your formula missing a column 'Id'  with a type of number. I think is impossible!

Comment: Try post your question at https://powerusers.microsoft.com with all details of lists and columns types

Comment: I found a temporary solution. I create a 'Librarian' book associated with a 'Librarian' User.

Soo i simplify the forum and  i can assign the book at the 'librarian':

Patch([@Book], Gallery4.Selected, { ID_User: LookUp(Book, ThisRecord.Title= "Librarian").ID_User})